# Can I force initialization for all possible enum values of an enum class class/function template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

I have a `template class` using an `enum class` as template parameter, defined in a header file:

```
// MyClass.h
enum class MyEnum {FOO, BAR};

template<MyEnum T>class MyClass {
  void doStuff();
  // ...
};
```

I would like to have the actual implementations of the member functions in a separate source file. I know, that in that case I have to enforce the initialization of the template for each case:

```
//MyClass.cpp
template<MyEnum T>void MyClass<T>::doStuff() {
  // ...
}
// Implementations of other functions

template class MyClass<MyEnum::FOO>;
template class MyClass<MyEnum::BAR>;
```

Typically, I know that I need the class with *all* possible values for the `enum` anyway, so I would like to tell the compiler that it should actually build the template class for each possible value *without explicitly mentioning each possibility*.

In other words: I want to replace the last two lines in the example by some automated code.

**Is this somehow possible?**

I would also like to do the same with template functions instead of a template class.

Comment: You mean `template class MyClass<MyEnum::FOO>;`?

Comment: I think it's possible to write a recursive template which instantiate a template with the next value in every iteration til you reach the last enum value.
However, unless you extern every template instance in the header, the compiler will instantiate them anyway in every translation unit you wanna use them...

Comment: Thanks, @Barry. Corrected my question accordingly.

Comment: @Melkon: thanks for your suggestion, but I guess for that I would at least need to make my enums iteratable, which I found to be possible, but not really elegant. Still, I'm gonna think about it.

Comment: You also can pass every value as variadic template... in this case you should write it explicitly tho.
Like this: Instantiate<EnumValue1, EnumValue2, ..., EnumValueN>;
It's maybe slightly better than if you should instantiate them one by one. Probably still not good enough solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to let the compiler know about all the possible specializations is to implement them in the same file. I can't think of a sane way to let the compiler know that a template class is specialized for every value in the domain.

If you have a bazillion of them, you could consider using the [X macro pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). Isolate all your cases in a header file (say `MyEnum.h`) like that:

```
#ifndef HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(e)
#define HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(e)
#endif

HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(FOO)
HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(BAR)
// add more HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(...) expressions for every other case you have

#undef HANDLE_ENUM_CASE
```

In your source file, you can then have:

```
enum class MyEnum {
#define HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(e) e,
#include "MyEnum.h"
}

// (class declaration here)

#define HANDLE_ENUM_CASE(e) template class MyClass<MyEnum::e>;
#include "MyEnum.h"
```

Comment: Not a big fan of `MyEnum.h` nuking `HANDLE_ENUM_CASE`, but X-macros are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, @zneak. Still, I accepted your answer rather for your statement: "I can't think of a sane way [...]". Probably it's the only correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days when enum were just custom names for integer values, it was trivial : we just added a MAX value as the last enum and iterated with a mere `for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)`.

If you were using a simple `enum MyEnum { FOO, BAR };` you could at least cast a MyEnum to an int, (but not the opposite, would be too easy). But with a `enum class MyEnum { FOO, BAR };` casting to an int is no defined either.

So the only C++11 enum way is ... the macro way proposed by zneak ... sniff :-(

If you do not like that (**I don't**) you have to forget `enum class` and use plain integers, or at least as typedef. And it is not all, a non-type template argument must be a constant expression, so you should also forget the non-type template construct.

It would lead to :

```
namespace MyEnum {

    typedef int MyEnum_t;
    enum MyEnum : MyEnum_t  { FOO, BAR, MAX };
}

class MyClass {
    MyEnum::MyEnum_t T;
public:
    MyClass(MyEnum::MyEnum_t t): T(t) {}
    void doStuff() {
        std::cout << T << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You should probably declare a copy constructor that makes sure that you only copy between compatible types, because the compiler can no longer control it. But as least you could do :

```
for(MyEnum::MyEnum_t e=0; e<MyEnum::MAX; e++) {
    MyClass obj(e);
    obj.doStuff();
}
```

BTW, as `MyClass` would no longer be a template, you could safely put the actual implementations of the member functions in a separate source file...

Comment: I do not think that this can be the expected answer. I only give it to show a possible alternative to the macro proposed by zneak, and its consequences.

Comment: Thanks, @Serge_Ballesta, I noticed that in some cases I actually do not need to use templates at all and can reduce to a function argument (like you did in the constructor). However, I also have functions where the return _type_ is actually dependent on the template argument, so that your solution can't work there.

Comment: @user2296653: so I cannot imagine anything else than  macros :-)